# Use argon2 to generate a key usable for Fernet

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, encryption, encoding

**My goal:** Take a plain-text password and generate a 32 byte token that can be used for Fernet encryption.

**What I've tried so far:**

```
>>> from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
>>> import argon2
>>> import base64
>>> hash = argon2.hash_password('abc'.encode(), hash_len=32)
>>> hash
b'$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=3,p=4$ee2ZpEZ5Q58HwIT91xQxgw$QrzxXCLBOnuzLgVPoccIPcaeF4mS4uvmrRBFzNXZbxw'
>>> Fernet(hash)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 34, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.
```

**I've then tried:**

```
>>> b64_hash = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(hash)
>>> b64_hash
b'j\xb8(\x9fh\xaf\xd7\xd9'
>>> Fernet(b64_hash)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 32, in __init__
    key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

So, I've fixed the first error, but now another (similar) one comes up.
What's the issue here?

Comment: https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md

Comment: Mhh, the specs sheet references way more rules than applicable for my case, it does work if I just base64 encode random 32 bytes

Comment: It looks very simple to me, for the key itself it's just two 16 byte values concatenated, or, yes, 32 random bytes. The token is only a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found is to use the `hash_secret_raw` function:

```py
import base64
import argon2
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

password = "abc"
key = argon2.low_level.hash_secret_raw(password.encode("utf-8"), salt=b"somesalt", time_cost=1, memory_cost=8, parallelism=1, hash_len=32, type=argon2.low_level.Type.D)
assert 32 == len(key)
b64_key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key)
cipher = Fernet(b64_key)
```

Basically, the `hash_password` function returns the actual hash with more information needed for hash verification. So the result of `hash_password` is longer than 32 bytes. `hash_secret_raw` returns only the actual 32 bytes hash.

Comment: I think hash_password_raw has been moved to argon2.low_level.hash_secret_raw()